# Find kernel name for a partition when only the label is known

Tags: linux, partition, disk

Condition: find reliably device name where disk label (`MasiWeek`) and disk size (`2 TB`) are known
Motivation: trying to determine what Ubuntu's GUI button *mount* does
Characteristics of the system

- Disk label is the name of the disc given by the user. It is listed in `/media/masi/` if mounted correctly.
- Command `lsblk -no name,label,partlabel` gives

  ```
  sda                    
  ├─sda1                 
  ├─sda2                 
  └─sda3                 
  sdb                    
  └─sdb1 MasiWeek
  ```
- I know the disk label is `MasiWeek` and its size is 2 TB, visible in the command as 1.8T. I want to find reliably such a disc such that I can do the following where I need the info for the variable `$label`

  ```
  # https://askubuntu.com/a/593375/25388
  partition=$(basename $(readlink $label))
  sudo mkdir /media/$USER/$label
  sudo mount /dev/$partition /media/$USER/$label
  ```

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Related: [What is the Equivalent Command to Ubuntu's GUI “Mount”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/801386/25388)

Comment: All right, so what are you trying to do here ? Figure out what is the kernel name (`sdb1` in this case) of a partition with a certain label (`MasiWeek` in this case) ?

Comment: Dude, as I said, you're trying to reinvent the wheel... Run `man udisksctl` and read the instructions there (it's what your "gui button" does underneath, to answer both questions).

Comment: @don_crissti How can you ask `udisksctl` a `sd*` with disk name and disk size without parsing? I do not see any parameters for them.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, the GUI almost certainly uses the `gvfs-mount` command: you can run `gvfs-mount --list --detail` and look for the `unix-device` field, and mount it (as user, not root) with something like `gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb`

Comment: @Masi I have attempted to answer in your related askubuntu question [What is the Equivalent Command to Ubuntu's GUI “Mount”?](http://askubuntu.com/a/801430/178692)

Comment: You're making this far more complicated than it needs to be.  `mount` already understands both `LABEL=name` and `UUID=uuid` arguments as well as the `/dev/xxxx` arg.  It also has `-L` and `-U` options.  So, just use `mount LABEL=MasiWeek /media/masi/MasiWeek` or `mount -L MasiWeek /media/masi/MasiWeek`

Comment: @cas Is `mount -L MasiWeek /media/masi/MasiWeek` the same as `gvfs-mount --device=/media/masi/MasiWeek`? There is no label -option in `gvfs-mount`.

Comment: i have no idea, i don't use gvfs-mount.  but given that you say that gvfs-mount doesn't have a label option, I'l take a wild guess and say that the answer is "No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `mount`'s `-L` option or specify the mount device with `LABEL=name`.

   e.g.

   ```
   mount LABEL=MasiWeek /media/masi/MasiWeek
   ```

   or

   ```
   mount -L MasiWeek /media/masi/MasiWeek
   ```

   `mount` also has a `-U` option and understands `UUID=uuid` if you prefer to use the block device's UUID.
2. The easiest way to get a list of all block devices, along with the LABEL and/or UUID details (if any) is to use `blkid`.  e.g.

   ```
   # blkid
   /dev/sda1: LABEL="kaliboot" UUID="c0182339-da69-4f30-b131-c2fdb778f6b0" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="6fb80985-01"
   /dev/sda2: UUID="4c367cee-8bed-41d5-b466-38c7f3a03330" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="6fb80985-02"
   /dev/sda3: LABEL="kaliroot" UUID="6bb6d228-0581-49ae-9d49-dd148c273ecc" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="6fb80985-03"
   ```

   Note that the swap partition has a UUID, but doesn't have a label.  That's because I didn't bother to use the `-L` option when I created it with `mkswap`.

   Note also that this can be slow and produce lots of output (one line per block device) if you have lots of LVM LVs or ZFS ZVOLs (as I do on my main machine, which is why i used the output from another machine) or similar.

Comment: Is it more stable to use `mkswap` with the option `label`? Do you do it that way? Better usability later?

Comment: it makes no difference to stability.  labels on swap partitions (and on filesystems too) are mostly cosmetic, also convenient so you don't have to remember the swap's /dev/ node or the long and ugly UUID.    I only mentioned it in my answer to highlight the fact that labels are optional.

Comment: How do you use swaps in your system everyday? I do not understand how I could benefit from it when I just create the swap and use it.

Comment: that's how you use it.  you create the swap device, run `swapon` (or put it in your `/etc/fstab`) and..........that's it. nothing more to do.  your system now has more virtual memory (RAM plus swap) available.  The kernel will swap stuff in and out of RAM as needed, automatically.  You really don't need to do anything more (except maybe enable `zswap` as I mentioned in my answer to your other, related question).

Comment: if you meant "how do i use a swap label", you use it the same as you use a filesystem label.  e.g. instead of something like  `/dev/sdaX none swap defaults,discard 0 0` in `/etc/fstab`, you'd use `LABEL=swaplabel none swap defaults,discard 0 0`.  You can also use `swapon -L swaplabel` instead of, e.g., `swapon /dev/sdaX`.

Answer (score 1):

If you only know the partition label and want to find the corresponding kernel name:

```
lsblk -rno label,name | awk '$1=="LABEL"{print $2}'
```

outputs something like `sdb3`. You can then mount the partition the same way your file manager does, via `udisksctl`:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/$(lsblk -rno label,name | awk '$1=="LABEL"{print $2}')
```